# Query hstore fields where value exists and equals x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `Widgets` model, which has around 3 core active records. One column is named 'form_values' which has the format:

```
"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"
{"a" => "1", "b" => "2", "product_type" => "1"}.to_json
```

I need to query all active records whose form_values contains key `a` and its value is 1.

I had written something that didn't work, like this:

```
required_widgets = Widget.find_by_sql("select id from  (select id, form_values from widgets where form_values!= '' and form_values::jsonb?'' and form_values::json->>'product_type' = '1') as required_widgets where (form_values::json->'a')::jsonb?'1' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [`hstore` data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html#AEN126956) supported by postgresql, it is rather easy:

Both of your use cases are [described in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html#AEN126956)

**1: check if a value is defined**

> hstore ? text

so for your use case

```
form_values::hstore ? 'a'
```

**2: select (and compare) a value**

> hstore -> text

so for your use case

```
form_values -> product_type 
# this returns '1'
```

**3: Adding them to a query:**

```
SELECT * FROM widgets
WHERE form_values::hstore ? 'a'
AND (form_values -> a)::integer = 1
```

You can also wrap parts of it into ActiveRecord:

```
Widget.where(
  form_values::hstore ? 'a' 
  AND (form_values -> a)::integer = 1
)
```

<sub>* **::integer** casts the string value to an integer. This will come in handy when querying for records where `a > 2`</sub>